# React Hooks Drawer Menu not Showing CSS Transition

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-hooks

My Menu Drawer is working except for the css transitions. I think whta is happening is, when I change the value of menuOpen (which is a useState), the DOM rerenders and the transition never happens. How do I stop this? I think I need to use the useRef I have already, but not sure how?

My Page Component with a white div that will be the drawer:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

        import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

        import './page.css';

        function Page({ someProps }) {
            const [ menuOpen, setMenuOpen ] = useState(false);
            const menuRef = useRef();

            const handleMenuClick = () => {
                setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
                console.log('MENU CLICKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', menuOpen);
            };

            const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
                console.log('CLICKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', event, menuRef.current);

                if (menuRef.current && !menuRef.current.contains(event.target) && menuOpen === true) {
                    setMenuOpen(false);
                }
            };

            useEffect(
                () => {
                    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false);
                    return () => {
                        document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false);
                    };
                },
                [ menuOpen ]
            );

            return (
                <Typography className="screen">
<div className="menuButton" onClick={handleMenuClick}>
                    MENU
                </div>
                    {menuOpen && <div ref={menuRef} className={`menuContainer ${menuOpen === true ? 'isOpen' : ''}`} />}
                </Typography>
            );
        }

        export default Page;
```

My page.css:

```
.menuContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: margin 1s ease-in;
    margin: 0 0 0 -250px;
}

.menuContainer.isOpen {
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    transition: margin 2s;
}
```

Comment: `menuContainer` is being **removed from the DOM**  when `menuOpen` is false (`{menuOpen && ....}`) - that's not what you want. Just leave it in the DOM the entire time regardless of the value of `menuOpen`

Comment: Brilliant! always the simple things!